# how to stop sending logs to Google Analytics(GA4 Mobile) in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, google-analytics-4

I am using:

```
 async Task Command_SetAnalyticsOptionFalse()
        {
            selectedAnalyticsEnabled = false;
            Analytics.SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
            await SetAnalyticsOption();
        }
```

I used this approach but it is not working. Can someone help me out with this problem?